# Psycopg2 Module clearly installed yet module not found

Tags: python, module, pip, package-management

I'm not sure whats happening but I seemed to have successfully installed psycopg2 with easy_install then checked with pip. My app errors out at the import statement. [proof of install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM1Xx.png)

If you think, updating pip would help, i've also had problems with that. In my venv it's version 7 but outside it's v 9. I get an exception during the uninstall of v 7.

Psycopg2 is also visible in requirements.txt from pip freeze
[errors out anyway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQXtB.png)

Comment: If it can't be imported, I'd say that's a pretty clear indication that it isn't properly installed.

Comment: Yeah, sure. But shouldn't there be an exception during the install? http://imgur.com/a/IIMXq

Comment: platform.architecture()[0] is '64bit'

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have installed `psycopg2` into the virtual environment, however, PyCharm is running with the system Python, and its standard library and site packages.

In PyCharm's project settings, configure the interpreter to point at the virtualenv.